# conversion of .img to binary file using R

Tags: r

I have a series of raster images which have to be converted to binary files. I request you to suggest a R code for conversion of all files at a time

Comment: What do you mean by "binary", raster format or bit-depth?

Comment: This isn't a very clear question.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming all your .img files are in one folder and the ENVI file format suffices as the binary output this R code works.

```
library(raster)

directory <- "/path/to/IMG/files"
setwd(directory)

## create vector containing all image filenames
Images <- dir(directory, pattern="\\.img$") #edit the pattern (case sensitive!) if you want to exclude/include images

## create the subdirectory
dir.create(file.path(directory, 'binary'))

for (i in 1:length(Images)){
  outRaster = raster(Images[i])
  writeRaster(outRaster, filename=paste(directory, '/binary/', Images[i], sep=""), format='ENVI') #write into subdirectory, keep original name
  }
```

You can look up the syntax and available file formats of writeRaster() and writeFormats() in the [raster package documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf).

May I suggest that instead of using R for this job you take a look at **GDAL**. Doing this task with the GDAL-tools would have a number of advantages:

- faster
- can be invoked from bash/batch scripts
- supports more file formats
- FOSS (just like R)

**Edit:**
Updated the code to incorporate helpful hints by Matthew Plourde.

Comment: +1 minor point, but the correct pattern to supply to `dir` in this case is `\\.img$`. The pattern you have now would match any file that contains any character followed by 'img' anywhere in its name. The parentheses are also unnecessary. Also, `file.path` exists so that you don't have to paste components of a path together. So something like `dir.create(file.path(directory, 'binary'))` would be sufficient.

Comment: Why are you importing rgdal? Also on the last line, you mean to write `format='ENVI'`? Additionally, `dir` will only return the filenames (not the full paths), unless you supply `full.names=TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. `rgdal` was indeed superfluous (I pasted code I used in a project, which required rgdal). `dir` only returning filenames is expected, since those are later used to write the files. One could leave out the `setwd()` and then use `full.names=TRUE` to work with absolute paths for input/output.

Comment: From a code efficiency standpoint you could make this much more streamlined. For example, could use "list.files" with full.names=TRUE and not have to actually set the working directory to the file(s) location. When explictly setting a working directory, you do not need a "Directory" variable because you can just use "getwd()". Also, in your regular expression it is not necessary to have "//" because the "$" suffices in limiting the wildcard to files ending with ".img"